# Snowflake - When faced with mixed content XML, how do you select the value of an XML element without including child xml elements?

Tags: sql, xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Consider the following SQL:

```
   SELECT 
    InlineXML.src:"@"      as Level1_ElementName
    ,InlineXML.src:"@name" as Level1_NameAttributeValue
    
    ,Level2.value:"@"      as Level2_ElementName        
    ,Level2.value:"@name"  as Level2_NameAttributeValue
    
    ,Level3.value:"@"      as Level3_ElementName
    ,Level3.value:"@name"  as Level3_NameAttributeValue
    
    ,Level4.value:"@"      as Level4_ElementName
    ,Level4.value:"@name"  as Level4_NameAttributeValue
    ,Level4.value:"$"      as Level4_ElementContent
FROM (
    SELECT PARSE_XML('
<Level1 name="L1">
  <Level2 name="L1.1">
      <Level3 name="L1.1.1">
          <Level4 name="L1.1.1.1">
              My value is L1.1.1.1
          </Level4>
          <Level4 name="L1.1.1.2">
          </Level4>          
      </Level3>
      <Level3 name="L1.1.2">
          <Level4 name="L1.1.2.1">
          </Level4>
      </Level3>
  </Level2>
</Level1>'
) as src) InlineXML
,LATERAL flatten(TO_ARRAY(InlineXML.src:"$")) AS Level2
,LATERAL flatten(TO_ARRAY(Level2.value:"$")) AS Level3
,LATERAL flatten(TO_ARRAY(Level3.value:"$")) AS Level4
WHERE GET(Level2.value, '@')::string = 'Level2' 
AND GET(Level3.value, '@')::string = 'Level3'
```

This works fine and selects out the attribute values and element names as you would expect.

[Results of working query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUyfZ.png)

If we add in some **mixed content** into the XML such as a value to our Level3 element, then **how do we select JUST THAT value of the element and not the child elements?**

For example, if we change the XML to:

```
<Level1 name="L1">
  <Level2 name="L1.1">
      <Level3 name="L1.1.1">
          Hello World! This is the value of the first level 3 element.
          <Level4 name="L1.1.1.1">
              My value is L1.1.1.1
          </Level4>
          <Level4 name="L1.1.1.2">
          </Level4>          
      </Level3>
      <Level3 name="L1.1.2">
          <Level4 name="L1.1.2.1">
          </Level4>
      </Level3>
  </Level2>
</Level1>
```

How do we select the value *"Hello World! This is the value of the first level 3 element.*"? I know we can use `level3.value:"$"` but that returns far more than I need:

```
[   "Hello World! This is the value of the first level 3 element.",   {     "$": "My value is L1.1.1.1",     "@": "Level4",     "@name": "L1.1.1.1"   },   {     "$": "",     "@": "Level4",     "@name": "L1.1.1.2"   } ]
```

**How do I just get the element value and not it's child element?**

Comment: `IFF(CHECK_XML(Level4.value) IS NOT NULL, Level4.value::TEXT, NULL)  AS level3` will return "Hello World! This is the value of the first level 3 element."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may look that it is simple to get value from array:

```
level3.value:"$"[0]
```

but it is not guaranteed that it is always the first element of array.

---

Alternative approach is based on [CHECK_XML](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/check_xml) function:

```
IFF(CHECK_XML(Level4.value) IS NOT NULL, Level4.value::TEXT, NULL)  AS level3
-- <=>
NVL2(CHECK_XML(Level4.value), Level4.value::TEXT, NULL)  AS level3
```

Entire query:

```
SELECT
     InlineXML.src:"@"     as Level1_ElementName
    ,InlineXML.src:"@name" as Level1_NameAttributeValue
    
    ,Level2.value:"@"      as Level2_ElementName        
    ,Level2.value:"@name"  as Level2_NameAttributeValue

    ,Level3.value:"@"      as Level3_ElementName
    ,Level3.value:"@name"  as Level3_NameAttributeValue
    
    ,NVL2(CHECK_XML(Level4.value), Level4.value::TEXT, NULL)  AS level3
    ,Level4.value:"@"      as Level4_ElementName
    ,Level4.value:"@name"  as Level4_NameAttributeValue
    ,Level4.value:"$"      as Level4_ElementContent
FROM (
    SELECT PARSE_XML('
<Level1 name="L1">
  <Level2 name="L1.1">
      <Level3 name="L1.1.1">
          Hello World! This is the value of the first level 3 element.
          <Level4 name="L1.1.1.1">
              My value is L1.1.1.1
          </Level4>
          <Level4 name="L1.1.1.2">
          </Level4>    
      </Level3>
      <Level3 name="L1.1.2">
          <Level4 name="L1.1.2.1">
          </Level4>
      </Level3>
  </Level2>
</Level1>
'
) as src) InlineXML
,LATERAL flatten(TO_ARRAY(InlineXML.src:"$")) AS Level2
,LATERAL flatten(TO_ARRAY(Level2.value:"$")) AS Level3
,LATERAL flatten(TO_ARRAY(Level3.value:"$")) AS Level4
WHERE GET(Level2.value, '@')::string = 'Level2' 
AND GET(Level3.value, '@')::string = 'Level3';
```